# Can any one help Type 'Observable<Detail>' is missing the folowing problem?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-http

```
  public ukmdetail: Detail = null

  constructor(
    private ukmserv: UkmService,
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.ukmdetail = this.ukmserv.getUkmByKode(params.kode)
    })
  }
```

```
  getUkmByKode(kode: string): Observable<Detail>{
    return this.http.get<Detail>(`${this.urlApi}/api/ukm/${kode}`);
  }
```

```
export interface Detail{
    info: string;
    result: {
        id: number,
        kode: string,
        nama: string,
        anggota: string,
        foto: string,
        deskripsi: string,
        created_at: string,
        updated_at: string,
    };
}
```

I got Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from type 'Detail': info, result when doin that code,
can someone help me solve this
what i want is i want to show the data that i got from the api
the data inside the api is like this

```
{"info":"This Info","result":{"id":2,"kode":"OL002","nama":"asd","anggota":12,"foto":"somelink","deskripsi":"somedesc","created_at":1573898337807,"updated_at":1573898337807
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the returned observable and then assign the received response to your variable  ukmdetail :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.ukmserv.getUkmByKode(params.kode).subscribe(
              resp => {
              this.ukmdetail = resp ;
           })
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe on Observables.

So change your ngOnInit to something like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.ukmserv.getUkmByKode(params.kode).subscribe(
        detail => this.ukmdetail = detail
      );
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ukmdetail is an Observable because getUkmByKode method is an http call, it returns an Observable, change it to

```
public ukmdetail: Observable<Detail>;
```

and then in your template you can use async pipe

```
<span>{{(ukmdetail | async)?.info}}</span>
```

async can unsubscribe automatically, so you don't have to do it manually.